# Non causal cost function reduction

Tags: signal-processing

is there a way to minimize a cost function in the form of cost = output(to be calculated) - function of(output to be calculated) + input provided. If yes, anyone kind enough to point me to a good learning link, to a short explanation would be even better!

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize ? For more specific suggestions, describe your `output` and `function` in more detail.

Comment: Thank you. Wil keep heed from next time!